# Passing multiple inputs to CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

I have vector of integers representing each character in the domain name and another vector of integers representing the timeline information. I need to give both these vectors as input to a CNN model to classify domain names as good or spam.

For instance,

Vector representing domain name -> 1 x 75 vector. Each element in the vector represents each character in the domain name. If there are 1000 domain names, then it will be a matrix of shape 1000 x 75

Vector representing timeline information -> 1 x 1440 vector. Each element representing number of mails sent from a particular domain for each minute. If there are 1000 domain names, then it will be a matrix of shape 1000 x 1440

How do I input these two vectors to a single CNN model?

My current model is given only the domain name as input,

```
def build_model(max_features, maxlen):
"""Build CNN model"""
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 8, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Convolution1D(6, 4, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(4, 4, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(2, 4, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
#model.add(Dense(180,activation='sigmoid'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 'f1score', 'precision', 'recall'])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In convolutions, you need a "length" dimension and a "channels" dimension.

(In 2D, they would be "width", "height" and "channels").

Now, I can't think of any way to relate the 75 characters with the 1440 minutes. (Maybe you can, and if you can state how, maybe we can work better)

Here is what I'm assuming:

- A sequence for the domain name, containing length 75.
- The domain name will have 8 channels (since your embedding layer has 8 outputs)
- Another sequence for the 1440 minutes.
- Only one channel for the e-mails per minute

So, we'd have two inputs:

```
from keras.layers import *

input1 = Input((75,))
input2 = Input((1440,))
```

Only the domain name should pass through an embedding layer:

```
name = Embedding(max_features, 8, input_length=maxlen)(input1)
```

Now, reshaping to fit the convolutional inputs `(None,length,channels)`.

```
# the embedding output is already (Batch, 75, 8) -- See: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/    

mails = Reshape((1440,1))(input2) #adding 1 channel at the end
```

Parallel convolutions:

```
name = Conv1D( feel free to customize )(name)
name = Conv1D( feel free to customize )(name)

mails = Conv1D( feel free to customize )(mails)
mails = Conv1D( feel free to customize )(mails)
```

Concatenate - Since they have totally different shapes, maybe we should simply flatten both (or you could think of fancy operations to match them)

```
name = Flatten()(name)
mails = Flatten()(mails)
out = Concatenate()([name,mails])

out = add your extra layers

out = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(out)
```

And finally we create the model:

```
from keras.models import Model
model = Model([input1,input2], out)
```

Train it like this:

```
model.fit([xName,xMails], Y, ....)
```

Comment: This model makes more sense. Thanks very much.

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a way to decide the number of outputs from embedding layer. I understand how embedding layer works but I wonder if there is any intuition behind choosing the number of output channels.

Comment: It's an open question. It depends on how much info, how many concepts are possible (and useful) to form from the inputs. These things must be experimented. Too few may not be enough for your task, too many may become heavy or make your model overfit. But there is no right number.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a multi-input network using Keras' functional API. Have a 1D convolution network separately for each input dimensions. Then concatenate the output of each of these networks and pass that concatenated vector into some shared fully-connected layers which sit on top of both of the other networks.

https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am wondering if using 2D convolution network work if I pass 2D input to the network?

Comment: Is there any relation you want to make between the 75 steps in name and the 1440 steps in e-mails? These two don't seem to fit together, and it seems you will really need to keep them separate for convolutions.